# ReactJS SetState not rerendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fluxible

I have:

JobScreen

```
handleSetView(mode, e) {
        this.setState({
            view: mode
        });
        console.log(this.state.view)
    }

    render() {
        return (

            <div className="jobs-screen">
                <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 job-list"><JobList view={this.state.view} /></div>
                <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 panel-container">
                    <div className="right-panel pull-right"><RightPanel handleSetView={this.handleSetView} /></div>
...
)
}
```

RightPanel

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="controls">
                    <span className="title">Views <img src="images\ajax-loader-bar.gif" width="24" id="loader" className={this.state.loading ? "pull-right fadeIn" : "pull-right fadeOut"}/></span>
                    <button onClick={this.props.handleSetView.bind(this, 'expanded')}><img src="/images/icons/32px/libreoffice.png" /></button>
                    <button onClick={this.props.handleSetView.bind(this, 'condensed')}><img src="/images/icons/32px/stack.png" /></button>
                    </div>
...
)}
```

JobList

```
render() {
        var jobs = [];
        this.state.jobs.forEach((job) => {
            jobs.push(
                <Job key={job.id} job={job} view={this.props.view} loading={this.state.loading} toggleTraderModal={this.props.toggleTraderModal} toggleOFTModal={this.props.toggleOFTModal}/>
            );
        });

        return (
            <div>
                {jobs}
            </div>
        );
    };
```

The problem is, is that the changing of the view state does not rerender any of the child elements.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Have you got any errors?

Comment: There are no errors.

Comment: This isn't a issue of state not re-rendering you just didn't bind your function

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure if it is the core of your problem, but:

```
handleSetView={this.handleSetView}
```

is wrong, because how js binds this. Use:

```
handleSetView={this.handleSetView.bind(this)}
```

instead.

Also,

```
this.setState({
  view: mode
});
console.log(this.state.view)
```

seems strange; note that `this.state` is not modified right after you call `setState`, it may took some time while React dispatches the scheduled `setState` operation. Put that `console.log` into render to see when it is actually called.

Finally, make sure, your components do not implement `shouldComponentUpdate` lifecycle method (you are probably not doing this explicitly, but if your component extends some class other than React.Component this may happen)

Comment: Genius :) I was missing .bind(this). What does that do exactly?

Comment: :)
It ensures, that `this` is correctly bounded to the component object when you call `handleSetView` (this does not happen automatically in js)

Comment: @Thomas Kulich I'm sure that this was just a silly mistake but you say this does not happen automatically in js, I think you mean in ES2015.

Comment: This is not the best way to handle this because a new function will be created on every re-render.  It's better to bind the `this.handleSetView` in the constructor or convert it to an es6 arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is in the context of the react Component so either pass the reference of `this` to you function `handleSetView`  or bind `this` as mentioned by @Tomas